# Calculation of Posterior distribution numerically

Tags: r, probability, self-study, bayesian, numerical-integration

For calculating posterior probabilities numerically, I did not understand that why is in the following codes they have divided by 0.001 in the denominator to calculate `Numeric_Posterior`?

```
Theta <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)

Likelihood <- pbinom(2, 10, Theta)
Prior <- dbeta(Theta, 4, 4)
Numeric_Posterior <- Likelihood * Prior/sum(Likelihood * Prior)/0.001

plot(Theta, Numeric_Posterior, type = "l", ylim = c(0, 4), xlab = expression(theta), 
     ylab = "")
lines(Theta, Prior, col = "red")
lines(Theta, Likelihood, col = "blue")
legend(0.5, 3.5, c("Posterior", "Likelihood", "Prior"), lty = 1, 
       col = c("black", "blue", "red"))

 abline(v = Theta[which.max(Numeric_Posterior)])
```

I thought it would be only `Numeric_Posterior <- Likelihood * Prior/sum(Likelihood * Prior)`.

(2) Also, to calculate the posterior probability that $\theta<0.5$, is the following R code appropriate?

```
length(Numeric_Posterior[which(Theta<0.5)])/length(Numeric_Posterior)
```

(3) Is there a way to find the posterior mean for this example?

Answer (score 4):

*Edited following clarification of the original question in comments*

Some key points:

- The attempt is to provide a posterior density
- using posterior density $\propto$ likelihood $\times$ prior density.
- Densities integrate to $1$, i.e. have $\int f(x) \, dx=1$.  You are approximating this with $\sum f(x) \,\delta x=1$ where $\delta x=0.001$. Try it with `sum(Prior * 0.001)` compared to `sum(Prior)` and you also want it to be true with `sum(Numeric_Posterior * 0.001)` rather than with `sum(Numeric_Posterior)`.
- In this particular example, the distribution has support on $[0,1]$ and each of the $1000$ (or $1001$) points in a sense represents a range of values of width $0.001$.
- `Likelihood * Prior` deals with the proportionality issue.
- `Likelihood * Prior/sum(Likelihood * Prior)` rescales this so the sum of this is $1$, and in a sense gives the posterior probability of each of $1000$ points representing the $1000$ ranges.
- but this is not a density, so you have to divide the probability for each of the mini-ranges by the width of that mini-range to get the density for that mini-range.
- Hence the `Likelihood * Prior/sum(Likelihood * Prior)/0.001` calculation.

There is some additional issues:

- `length(Numeric_Posterior[which(Theta<0.5)])/length(Numeric_Posterior)` is not going to work, as it asks what proportion of the $1000$ or $1001$ are less than $0.5$ which is obviously about half of them by construction.  You could use the cumulative sum of the densities times their widths with  `Theta[max(which(cumsum(Numeric_Posterior * 0.001) < 0.5))] + 0.001/2` or something similar.  The `+ 0.001/2` is because you have chosen the highest point with cumulative probability below `0.5`  for the median. You could have chosen the lowest point with cumulative probability above `0.5`
  instead, which would be `0.001`  higher, and going halfway between them is a possible compromise
- `sum(Theta * Numeric_Posterior * 0.001)` gives the posterior mean
- `Theta[which.max(Numeric_Posterior)]`, as you use, gives the posterior mode (MAP if you must, but why invent a new acronym?)
- `Theta <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)` leads to $1001$ points representing ranges of width $0.001$ and this has a tiny effect on the calculation. `Theta <- ppoints(1000)` would give the thousand points $0.0005, 0.0015, 0.0025, \ldots, 0.9995$ as the mid-point of each mini-range

You have said in comments *"The problem of my posted example is: we have thrown a coin 10 times, and we just know heads appear less than 3 times."* This would have been useful to have had in the original question, as it justifies using the CDF `pbinom(2, 10, Theta)` as proportional to the likelihood rather than the pmf `dbinom(2, 10, Theta)` which would have been suitable for *"we have thrown a coin 10 times, and we just know heads appeared 2 times."*

Using `Likelihood <- pbinom(2, 10, Theta)` (and `Theta <- ppoints(1000)`) would give

```
Theta[max(which(cumsum(Numeric_Posterior * 0.001) < 0.5))] + 0.001/2 # median
# 0.297
sum(Theta * Numeric_Posterior * 0.001)                               # mean
# 0.3046875
Theta[which.max(Numeric_Posterior)]                                  # mode
# 0.2815
```

By comparison, using `Likelihood <- dbinom(2, 10, Theta)` (and `Theta <- ppoints(1000)`) should give a Beta distribution with $\alpha=6, \beta=12$ so with median `qbeta(0.5,6,12)` i.e. $0.3270381$, mean $\frac{6}{6+12}\approx 0.3333$ and mode  $\frac{6-1}{6+12-2}=0.3125$ and in fact gives

```
Theta[max(which(cumsum(Numeric_Posterior * 0.001) < 0.5))] + 0.001/2 # median
# 0.327
sum(Theta * Numeric_Posterior * 0.001)                               # mean
# 0.3333333
Theta[which.max(Numeric_Posterior)]                                  # mode
# 0.3125
```

which is even closer than you might expect with precision of $0.001$, but does suggest that this method gives reasonable results.

Comment: The problem of my posted example is: we have thrown a coin 10 times, and we just know heads appear less than 3 times. I have few questions: (1) Why did you add  0.001/2 to find out the the probability of theta less than 0.5? (2) How is the true mean (1/3)? (3) How is the true mode (5/16)?

Comment: Another question,  If we divide sum(Likelihood * Prior) so the sum of this is 1, then why is not `Likelihood * Prior/sum(Likelihood * Prior)` density?

Comment: You should have written *"we have thrown a coin 10 times, and we just know heads appear less than 3 times"* at the beginning: my answer was based on *"we have thrown a coin 10 times, and we know heads appeared 2 times"* so giving a posterior distribution of a Beta distribution with  $\alpha=6, \beta=12$.

Comment: The `+ 0.001/2` is because you have chosen the highest point with cumulative probability below $0.5$ for the median.  You could have chosen the lowest point with cumulative probability above $0.5$ instead, which would be $0.001$ higher, and going halfway between them is a possible compromise.

Comment: A density has $\int f(x)\, dx=1$.  You are approximating this with $\sum f(x)\, \delta x=1$ where $\delta x=0.001$.  Try it with `sum(Prior * 0.001)` and you also want it to be true with `sum(Numeric_Posterior * 0.001)`  rather than with  `sum(Numeric_Posterior)`.

Comment: I have incorporated some of these comments into my reply